# Redshift concurrency scaling

Tags: amazon-redshift

We have enabled concurrency scaling, SQA, and auto WLM on a Redshift cluster with RA3 nodes. For some reason all queries run on the main cluster and no concurrency scaling cluster is launched even though the queries on the main cluster are queuing up a lot, e.g. one query was queued for 500s and then executed in 2s.

We get the following message in relation to it:

Concurrency Scaling inelegible query - Cumulative time not met

Concurrency Scaling ineligible query - Query has state on Main cluster

The docs don't say anything about what this could mean

Does concurrency scaling and SQA work at all?